# Сохранение информации в словарь Pyhton

Tags: python, словари, while

Не могу разобраться как сохранять информацию о более чем двух пользователей.
Выводит только последнего введенного пользователя.
Буду очень благодарен, так как инфы не нашел.

```
user_name = {}
arhive = True

while arhive:
   user_names = input("Pleas creat a nickname: ")
   location = input("Where are you from: ")
   pin = input("Create a pin: ")

   user_name['Name'] = user_names
   user_name['Location'] = location
   user_name['Pin'] = pin

finis = input("Want to register one more user?(yes/no)?: ")
   if 'yes' in finis:
       continue
   if 'no' in finis:
       print ("You have successfully register.")
       arhive = False

for key,value in user_name.items():
   print (f"{key}: {value}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вариант 1:

если нужен словарь - так и используйте словарь где в качестве ключа - имя

```
user_name = dict()
arhive = True

while arhive:
   user_names = input("Pleas creat a nickname: ")
   location = input("Where are you from: ")
   pin = input("Create a pin: ")

   user_name[user_names] = {'location': location, 'pin': pin}

   finis = input("Want to register one more user?(yes/no)?: ")
   if 'no' in finis:
       print ("You have successfully register.")
       arhive = False

for key, value in user_name.items():
   print (f"{key}: {value}")
```

вариант 2:

или используйте список, где в качестве элемента будет словарь:

```
user_name = list()
arhive = True

while arhive:
   user_names = input("Pleas creat a nickname: ")
   location = input("Where are you from: ")
   pin = input("Create a pin: ")

   user_name.append({'Name': user_names, 'Location': location, 'Pin': pin})

finis = input("Want to register one more user?(yes/no)?: ")
   if 'no' in finis:
       print ("You have successfully register.")
       arhive = False

for obj in user_name:
   print (f"{obj[name]}: {obj[location]}, {obj[pin]}")
```

P.S.

а вы принципиально у слов последние буквы отрезаете?

Comment: Спасибо, нет не принципиально, английский не очень хорошо знаю, и когда пишу код не обращаю на это внимание.

Comment: Еще раз большое спасибо

Comment: первый вариант (со словарем) будет работать только если все имена юзеров уникальны (что фактически мало вероятно).